# How to set type to variable that is in the process of setup in Typescript

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I have `PanelService.getSetupOrder(route.params.id)` which returns me 4 variables:

1. data
2. pending
3. error
4. refresh

In the docs I've found that you can write `data: order` to store data in order variable.

I'm using Typescript and I'm wondering whether I could set order variable to Ref<Order> type

I've tried doing something like this: `const { data: order: Ref<Order>, pending, error, refresh } = await PanelService.getSetupOrder(route.params.id)` and `const { data: (order: Ref<Order>), pending, error, refresh } = await PanelService.getSetupOrder(route.params.id)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've changed method `getSetupOrder` to return `Promise<_AsyncData<Order, true | Error>>`, previously it automatically was `Promise<_AsyncData<unknown, true | Error>>`